# Converting MODISL2 file into GeoTIFF and reprojection using Python pyhdf package

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, modis-reprojection-tool

I'm new with Python for remote sensing, I got a problem when converting MODISL2 data (atmospheic corrected by Seadas L2gen) into GeoTIFF file, I select two bands (Rrs and L2flag), and I got a result with weird projection:

```
import gdal
import numpy as np
from numpy import shape
from pyhdf.SD import *
from osgeo import osr


in_tiff_path = r'D:\PythonTest\TSS calculation'
hdf_obj = SD('MODIS_2008097_SWIR.hdf')

# get attributes, layers, and single layer of Rrs
attr = hdf_obj.attributes()
dateset = hdf_obj.datasets()

columns = int(attr['Number of Pixel Control Points'])
rows = int(attr['Number of Scan Control Points'])

Rrs = hdf_obj.select('Rrs_1240').get()  # when printing Rrs here, array with all negative values was obtained
d_Rrs = Rrs.astype(np.float32)

# convert negative values of hdf  to real pixel value array
real_Rrs = (d_Rrs + 25000) / 500000
real_Rrs[real_Rrs < 0] = 0

# L2_flag
l2 = hdf_obj.select('l2_flags').get()
d_l2 = l2.astype(np.int32)

# create a tiff file
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

out_tiff = driver.Create("MODIS_2008097.tif", columns, rows, 2, gdal.GDT_Float32)
out_tiff.SetGeoTransform((attr['Upper Left Longitude'], 0.055908203125, 0, attr['Upper Left Latitude'], 0, -0.019866943359375))

# get bands
out_tiff.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(real_Rrs)
out_tiff.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(d_l2)

# define an empty projection, import WGS84

ref = osr.SpatialReference()
ref.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
s = ref.ExportToWkt()
# set projection

out_tiff.SetProjection(s)
out_tiff.FlushCache()
```

[image: result]

The size of result image was different to that projected by Seadas or Beam sorftware (looks longer, it is also not facing exactly due north).

By the way, the geotransform parameter was obtained by a Geotiff file build by my input hdf file using Seadas software, because I could not find all geotransform parameters in hdf metadata (no pixel size description), and I don't understand what caused the projection problem.

Comment: what's the projection of your input data? Also, are you sure about the pixel-size (0.055908203125, -0.019866943359375), perhaps your input data doesn't have a uniform grid?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, my input hdf data has no projection since I didn’t set its projection after downloading it, and it’s a result of Seadas L2gen atmospheric correction from MODL1B data. 
Also, I’m not sure whether the pixel sizes are correct, since I could not find pixel sizes from input hdf file, but when I convert same hdf into tiff manually(using Seadas), I found both projection and pixel sizes from tiff metadata as:
ModelPixelScaleTag：0.055908203125, 0.019866943359375, 0.0  
GeographicTypeGeoKey：GCS_WGS_84

Answer (score 1):

1. Check our [FAQ](http://hdfeos.org/help/faq/index.php) page.
2. Under DATA RECIPE, there's a question and answer regarding GeoTIFF conversion.
3. If you click the Python link, you can see that it uses `pyresample`.
   Please try the similar method that [the OMI example](http://hdfeos.org/zoo/MORE/GESDISC/OMI/OMI-Aura_L2-OMAERUV_2019m0801t0453-o80020_v003-2019m0802t194820.SUB.he5.py) used.